# Best way to add a React frontend to a existing Node.js / Express REST API backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, web-architecture

I have an existing backend with a REST API written using node.js/express.
I can call urls e.g. /getallhouses and get the corresponding JSON object.
Using a mobile app, this is rather straightforward as you just call the REST API and process the data.
As I need to also add a webapp e.g. with React.js, it seems more murky.

What is the best way of implementing this webapp strategy?

Creating a stand-alone react.js app which will be called by the user first and then is using the REST API like a mobile app and hosting that react.js app on a different server?
Or is it better to start from the already existing express/node backend and serving the initial index.html file by

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'views/index.html'));
```

and putting all react.js related code into views and letting the backend serving the required react.js app to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably that you create a react app with [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) and compile it to a bundle with something like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Then you could host your page completely static.

Comment: Thank you. Since I'm not familiar with webpack, do you know a good resource for a start using this stack?

Comment: @StefanBadi Yes look on youtube for LevelupTuts. It's a great source for everthing with react.